# Bootstrap collapse is not triggered when there is onclick handler to one element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a collapse Bootstrap :

```
<div id="stat" style="border-style: ridge;border-width: 1px;border-radius: 3px;display:none;">
   <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseVehicules" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseVehicules" style="width: 100%;">
      <div style="float:left;">boutons</div><div id="chevron" data-nb-clics="0" style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse" id="collapseVehicules">
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
   </div>
</div>
```

As you can see there is the `#chevron` `div` inside the button. I coded an handler to it :

```
$("#chevron").on("click", function() {
      if (parseInt($(this).data("nbClics")) % 2 == 0) {
        $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
      } else {
        $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
      }
      $(this).data("nbClics", parseInt($(this).data("nbClics"))+1);
});
```

At runtime when I click the `#chevron` element then the collapse does not work but only the `#chevron`'s content is changed !

Comment: how will you click if  chevron is hidden

Comment: it is not hidden but it is changed to another fontawesome icon.

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#chevron` element is a div inside the button, im guessing the div click event never bubbles down to the button. You can always add to the code you already have:

```
$('#collapseVehicules').collapse("toggle");
```

edit: you said it doesnt work, since you dont want to provide your code, here is a sample that does: https://jsfiddle.net/rp4e2s1k/

Comment: can you create a fiddle, so we can exactly see what the issue is

Comment: in your fiddle the fontawesome does not trigger the collapse when clicked ; and that is also my problem.

Comment: It does for me, it starts off collapsed with a right chevron. When you click the chevron, the collapse expands and the chevron is down.
edit: you can add "toggle" as an argument to the collapse function if that is the functionality you are looking for
https://jsfiddle.net/rp4e2s1k/

Comment: I did, however i you can better express what your requirements are... Doenst work is not the same as it doesnt do what I originally wanted.